# Ace editor set text selection

Tags: ace-editor, textselection

My text is:

> My favourite singer is {Bruce Springsteen} and he was born in New Jersey.

I want to programmatically select the text between the curly braces including them. I cannot find a straightforward way.

Answer (score 10):

you can do `editor.find("{Bruce Springsteen}")`
or

```
var Range = require("ace/range").Range;
editor.selection.setRange(new Range(0, 23, 0, 42));
// use .setRange(.., true) for setting cursor at the beginning of the selection
```

Comment: I found out I had to write: var Range = ace.require("ace/range").Range

Comment: if you don't want to dirty your code with filthy requires, it seems new ace.Range(0, 23, 0, 42) works fine.